# simplify substring replacement list

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, string

I wrote a script that plays music. but the files have weird names.

say I have this string of a filename

`Muzzy__Break_Away__28feat._Priority_One_29__5BMonstercat_EP_Release_5D.mp3`

and I want to achieve this

`Muzzy Break Away feat Priority One`

So far I've got this in bash.

```
file="whatever";
file=${file//_/" "};
file=${file//[0123456789ABCDEF][0123456789ABCDEF]/""};  #replaces bytes
file=${file//.extension1/""};
file=${file//.extension2/""};
file=${file//.extensionn/""}; #many more, e.g. .mp3
file=${file//word1/""};
file=${file//word2/""};
file=${file//wordn/""}; #many more, e.g. Monstrcat
file=${file//./""};
echo "$file";
```

Is there any way to simplify this in 1 command in the same order (case sensitive)?

Comment: Which `B` is in the result, the one from `B2` or the one from `1362B`? Also, if you have several of these names to be converted, can you add some more examples (both input and expected output) to make it easier to find a common pattern?

Comment: Can you provide a real world filenames (may be obfuscated) and expected output? E.g. fileX -> fileZ). With provided example there are way too many questions. PS. Looks like it would be much easier to use `sed` or `perl` with a single regex instead of pure shell substitution.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iRSrV the real file names

Comment: Please edit them into the question as text, including the expected result for each. We can't guess which parts of the original filename are import to you.

Comment: Just from looking at the screenshot it seems that `_` is used both as a delimiter between parts *and* as a replacement for a space within a part. As the name doesn't seem to start after the same number of `_` this will be rather tricky to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might call out to perl:

```
formatted=$( perl -lpe '
        s/([0-9A-F]{2})/chr hex $1/eg;   # hex to ascii
        s/_+/ /g;                        # underscores to space
        s/\[[^]]*\]//g;                  # remove bracketed text
        s/[^[:alnum:][:blank:]]//g;      # remove non-alphanumeric,non-blank chars
    ' <<<"${file%.*}"
)
echo "$formatted"
```

```
Muzzy Break Away feat Priority One
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Those `_28` look like the hex encoding of some characters. Maybe you'd like something like (with `zsh` instead of `bash`):

```
$ autoload zmv
$ zmv -n '*.mp3' '${${f//(#b)_([0-9A-F](#c2))/${(#)$((0x$match))}}//_/ }'
mv -- Muzzy__Break_Away__28feat._Priority_One_29__5BMonstercat_EP_Release_5D.mp3 Muzzy\ \ Break\ Away\ \(feat.\ Priority\ One\)\ \[Monstercat\ EP\ Release\].mp3
```

If the point is to rename:

```
Muzzy__Break_Away__28feat._Priority_One_29__5BMonstercat_EP_Release_5D.mp3
```

to

```
Muzzy  Break Away (feat. Priority One) [Monstercat EP Release].mp3
```

(remove the `-n` (for dry-run) if happy).

If you have the file name in `$file` and want the *nicer* representation for display, use:

```
set -o extendedglob # (that's on by default in zmv)
display=${${${file//(#b)_([0-9A-F](#c2))/${(#)$((0x$match))}}//_/ }:r}
```

- `(#b)` activates back-references (so `$match[1]` in the replacement be the first string captured in the pattern)
- `${(#)var}` interprets the content of `$var` as a number and expand to the character with the corresponding codepoint
- `$var:r` get the rootname (remove extension) of the filename in `$var`.

Comment: well, this could help me. but renaming the files isn't what i want. Some of the players I use to play files doesn't recognize "(". anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should probly not use bash search/replace to do this stuff, if the file have ID3 meta data you should read it from there and use it with a template you like to have.

```
$ id3v2 -l file.mp3

Title  : Computer Love                   Artist: Zapp                          
Album  : Golden Gems-80s                 Year: 2017, Genre: Pop (13)
Comment:                                 Track: 29
id3v2 tag info for 29-zapp-computer_love-f3b5b5db.mp3:
TRCK (Track number/Position in set): 29/29
TPE1 (Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)): Zapp
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): Computer Love
TCON (Content type): Pop (13)
TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): Golden Gems-80s
TYER (Year): 2017
```

Then you can use tools like awk/sed/cut/grep to save the info into variables like this,

```
Artist=$(id3v2 -l file.mp3 | grep "TPE"  | awk -F: '{print $2}')
Title=$( id3v2 -l file.mp3 | grep "TIT2" | awk -F: '{print $2}')

mv file.mp3 "${Artist} - ${Title}.mp3"
```

But i really recommend using tools like [MP3Tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/)/[MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) to manage your music files, it will give you live preview, and allow you to roll back in case you did something wrong.

Comment: This. This could be better. for me. I'll mark it awnsered. although it's not THE anwser to the title question.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the required output using the following `sed` command:

```
echo "Muzzy__Break_Away__28feat._Priority_One_29__5BMonstercat_EP_Release_5D.mp3" \
  | sed "s/_[0-9]\{2\}_.*//g" | sed "s/[_0-9\.]/ /g"| sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"
```

Output

```
Muzzy Break Away feat Priority One
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end. This is what I got. I put everything in a separate script file. Also, as one of above answers said, id3v2. most my mp3 files didn't have that extension.

```
#/bin/bash
echo "Raw File Playlist" > $dir/$pmp/file;
ls dir/$map/|sort -R >> $dir/$pmp/file;
echo "Playlist" > $dir/$pmp/filename;
t=$(wc -l < $dir/$pmp/file);
for ((i=2;i<=t;i++));
do
f=$(sed -n "${i}{p;q;}" $dir/$pmp/file);
f=${f//120BPM/XXXBPM};
f=${f//_[0123456789ABCDEF][0123456789ABCDEF]/""};
f=${f//__/-};
f=${f//--/-};
f=${f//-/ - };
f=${f//_/ };
f=${f//  / };
f=${f//  / };
f=${f//  / };
f=${f//.flac/""};
f=${f//.html/""};
f=${f//.[azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn1234567890][azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn1234567890][azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn123456790]/""};
f=${f//[Ss]ubtitles/};
f=${f//[Mm]onstercat/};
f=${f//[Vv]ideo/};
f=${f//[EL]P/};
f=${f//[Ee]xclusive/};
f=${f//[Cc][Dd]/};
f=${f//[Rr]elease/};
f=${f//[Ll]yrics/};
f=${f//[Ll]yric/};
f=${f//[Dd]ownload/};
f=${f//[Oo]fficial/};
f=${f//FREE/};
f=${f//[Ff]ree/};
#f=${f//./ };
f=${f//XXXBPM/120bpm};
f=$(LC_ALL=C sed -r 's/^[^[:alpha:]]+//' <<< "$f");
echo "$f" >> $dir/$pmp/filename;
done;
exit;
```

Gives pretty decent output. It takes all the names, changes it and saves them to a file.